# How would I write a SQL statement to find child-parent pairs?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a SQL statement to find the descendants of the fact 'a'

```
Table name: facts_and_parents

Table format:
|---------------------|------------------|
|      **Field**      |   **Data Type**  |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          fact       |      text        |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          parent     |      text        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive CTE. For example:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select fact, parent from facts_and_parents where parent = 'a'
 union all
  select f.fact, f.parent
  from n
  join facts_and_parents f on f.parent = n.fact
)
select * from n;
```